# Is it possible to use ApiFuture in Gradle, Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently trying to use "ApiFuture" because tasks are a pain to use throughout a big project. Is there any way that I can use ApiFutures in my android project? I have searched the web and haven't been able to find anything. The Android project is supported by Gradle if that information helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `implementation`

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0'
}
```

For more information you can take a look at [Google Api Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup) and if you want an example take a look at this [firebase-asynchronous-operations-with-admin-java-sdk-82ca9b4f6022](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-asynchronous-operations-with-admin-java-sdk-82ca9b4f6022), this guy is using `ApiFuture`

Comment: Daniel, your question says "Is it possible use ApiFuture?" And my question is yes, implementing this library, if you need something else, just be clear when trying to write a question.

Comment: Look up at my comment above

Comment: Edited my question also this git is working for him : https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/build.gradle