# Reading data from Firestore. Resolving the ApiFuture import

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read from a Firestore database in a Java application. I am following the guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#read_data.

In order to read documents, I need to declare the type `ApiFuture`, which is found in the following import, `import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture`. In order to import it, I need to add the Google API Client, found here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/.

I followed the instructions for Maven, adding the following dependencies in my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<project>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.32.1</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have added the following modules in my `module-info.java` file:

```
requires google.api.client;
requires google.cloud.core;
requires com.google.api.core;
```

In the `ApiFuture.class` file, it defines the package as:

```
package com.google.api.core;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

/**
 * A Future that can have a listener added.
 *
 * <p>Similar to Guava's {@code ListenableFuture}, but redeclared so that Guava could be shaded.
 */
public interface ApiFuture<V> extends Future<V> {
  void addListener(Runnable listener, Executor executor);
}
```

But none of them seem to work. What is the correct way to require the module? Where can I find it?

Comment: Are you getting an error for missing dependencies, if yes please share.
Also check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463978/is-it-possible-to-use-apifuture-in-gradle-android-project)and [Thread](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the `com.google.api.core` module was actually found in the `com.google.api.apicommon` module https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/api-common/latest/overview). I needed to add `requires com.google.api.apicommon;` to my `module-info.java` package.